# How can I use multiple rows in where clause?

Tags: c#, sql, where-clause, firebird

```
TRAVEL    |  SIZE
0         |  0.41
2.5       |  0.45
5.0       |  0.50
7.5       |  0.54
10        |  0.58
```

I'm using Firebird database.
The ultimate goal is to get the travel according to given size.
The problem that I'm facing is that the given size is continuous.

For example, given size is 0.47.
And then, travel is gotten from Interpolation formula : `(0.47-0.45)*(5.0-2.5)/(0.5-0.45)+2.5 = 3.5`

Actually I tried to calculate in C# after extracting 2 rows around the given size. But I got stuck to extract 2 rows.

How do I solve this issue.

Comment: I would suggest using two queries instead of trying to do it in one - one query would `select where size > value` and the other `select where size < value`, and select only the first result each time (in LINQ that would be `Take(1)`).

Comment: Don't know about FireBird Db. In nomal sql, I'd do `select top(2) * from table order by abs(size-@givensize)`

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you're trying to solve? Extracting those two rows, or something else?

Comment: Can you put the code which you tried?

Comment: @MatJ `TOP(2)` is not standard SQL. For this Firebird 3 and later have the SQL standard [`FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch), and earlier versions have [`select first 2 ...`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-first-skip)

Comment: Also specify which version of Firebird you're using.

Comment: Why would you want to calculate only single pair? Won't you want to also calculate `0.54 - 0.50` case and `0.54 - 0.45` cases? i believe you have to read all this table and then calculate the whole matrix (DB to array, then nested loop) or at least whole vector (read ordered query with simple FSM).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks for the heads up.. not aware of that. So he can use fetch next 2 rows to solve the problem?

Comment: @MatJ If your assumptions about the problem the OP tries to solve, then yes.

Comment: @Arioch'The The value 0.47 is between 0.45 and 0.50, and the OP needs to interpolate based on those boundaries. Calculating the other values makes no sense to me.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it depends on all the calculated values and formulas which may vary. Right where we are it seems mere summing would suffice, but i preferred to keep it generic. Sometimes with non-linear formulae you would need a full matrix. // Unless this is a huge table with very infrequent access i still have intuition it would be better to once read-it-all and calculate-it-all in one loop.

Comment: @Mat J thank you for brilliant answer! To make up query according to your reply , i tried using this query, SELECT * FROM (SELECT FIRST 2 TRAVEL, SIZE FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY (SIZE - 0.47 )) ORDER BY SIZE;

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `lead()` for this purpose:

```
select (case when 0.47 = size then travel
             else travel + (next_travel - travel) * (0.47 - size) / (next_size - size)
        end) as imputed_size
from (select t.*,
             lead(size) over (order by size) as next_size,
             lead(travel) over (order by size) as next_travel
      from t
     ) t
where 0.47 >= size and
      (0.47 < next_size or next_size is null);
```

In older versions of Firebird, you can use correlated subqueries to get the next values.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I implement your suggestion and get the result successfully! But interface formula should be corrected from  else size + (next_travel - travel) * (0.47 - size) / (next_size - size) to else travel+ (next_travel - travel) * (0.47 - size) / (next_size - size)   other things are prefect!!